# C# How to copy file into Program(x86) folder with Wiindows service

Tags: c#, wcf, service, permissions

I've made an Updater application to update my main project. This Updater is composite by two parts :  WPF GUI and WCF Windows Service. I need to copy file form desktop folder into ProgramFile(x86)/Mainproject/bin/Debug for my scope. When I copy file with my service I have permission error on access file. How can I solve it?

Comment: Make an installer

Comment: Can you explain me better what do you intend for installer?

Answer (score 1):

This is because Windows Services run as the LOCAL SYSTEM user by default, which does not have write permissions. You should change the user that service runs as by right clicking it in the **Services** listing, going to Properties, selecting the Logon tab, and then selecting a different user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, there is a method to do so programmatically?

Comment: It's not good etiquette for Windows Vista+ apps to write willy nilly to the Program Files folders

Comment: @AntoG you might be able to specify the requested user when making the installer, but I'm not sure there's a way to do it programmatically. I'm inclined to say there isn't, as that would potentially count as escalation of privileges and a security no-no.